# Efficiently determine if two of three items in a list are the same

Tags: python, algorithm, list

What is the most efficient way to determine if exactly two elements in a list are the same? For example:

```
>>> has1dup(["one", "one", "two"])
True
>>> has1dup(["one", "two", "three"])
False
>>> has1dup(["one", "one", "one"])
False
```

I have successfully done this using if/else statements. However, if the list were larger, the task of writing out each possibility for a pair would become very difficult and time consuming. Is there a faster/simpler way to accomplish this?

Here is what I have tried:

```
def has1dup(lst):
    if lst[0] == lst[1] and lst[1] != lst[2]:
        return True
    elif lst[1] == lst[2] and lst[2] != lst[0]:
        return True
    elif lst[0] == lst[2] and lst[2] != lst[1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see how many unique values are there with a `set`. If there is one less item in the set than in the list, one was a duplicate:

```
def has1dup(lst):
    return len(lst)-1 == len(set(lst))
```

Comment: It checks if exactly two items in the list are the same. You cant generalize to find tripples though (they might just be two pairs), but that wasn't the question.

Comment: +1, same as the solution I eventually came up with (after misreading question) but yours was more succinct.

Comment: This only works if the elements in the list implement `__hash__` (which is true of most builtin-types), but stuff like `has1dup([[1], [1], [2]])` will raise an error, since lists are not hashable. Even user defined objects will not behave as expected if hash is not "significant". `has1dup([X(), X(), Y()])` for `X` and `Y` defined as empty classes returns False.
Since the question uses strings, this shouldn't be a problem, though.

Comment: This solution is incomplete as it's assuming there are not any other items having same values. However for sequence having length of 3, its fine, because there indeed does not have space for other items having same values.

Comment: @okm, perhaps you might come up with an example of what you mean. As per my response to your comment on my answer, I believe this works fine on any size list.

Comment: @paxdiablo probably I misunderstood the words "exactly two elements in a list are the same": if it means there are *ONLY* two elements having same value, you and Jochen are right. Just thought it meant there are two elements having same value...

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from collection import Counter
>>> 2 in Counter(["one", "one", "two"]).values()
True
>>> 2 in Counter(["one", "two", "three"]).values()
False
```

*update*
If you want there are only two same items

```
Counter(seq).values().count(2) == 1
```

The `Counter` works for Python 2.7+, for lower versions you could do it manually

```
def counter(seq): 
    r = {}
    for x in seq:
        r[x] = r.setdefault(x, 0) + 1 # or defaultdict
    return r
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work properly on the list 1,1,2,2. Isn't it supposed to be _exactly_ two elements?

Comment: Sorry, okm, I have reversed my downvote because the question title does indeed specify two of three - it's only a section in the question body that asks about longer lists (as an additional point).

Comment: @paxdiablo that's fine, the question is not that clear and determined, I've updated the answer also.

Comment: @paxdiablo About your comment "the list 1,1,2,2. Isn't it supposed to be exactly two elements?", did you implicitly mean that `[1, 1, 2, 2]` is supposed to be exactly two elements or negative? I'm not native English speaker and want to make sure the actual meaning of your words. If it's the first one, seems you was confused as well =p

Comment: I think 1,1,2,2 should return _false_ since it doesn't have exactly two values that are identical - it actually has two groups of two. So 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 would be true but 1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7 would give false. That's my understanding but, as everyone points out, the question could be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily and nicely using [the `any()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
def has_duplicates(seq):
    return any(seq.count(x) > 1 for x in seq)
```

Example:

```
>>> has_duplicates([1, 1, 2])
True
>>> has_duplicates([1, 2, 2])
True
>>> has_duplicates([1, 2, 3])
False
```

If you only want to find where two and only two items are the same, just change the condition:

```
any(seq.count(x) == 2 for x in seq)
```

If you want to find where there is one, and only one instance of two, and only two items, we can do that too, although it requires more work:

```
def any_n(iterable, n):
    seen = 0
    for value in iterable:
        if value:
            if seen >= n:
                return False
            else:
                seen += 1
    return seen == n

def has_one_value_repeated_n_times(seq, n):
    return any_n((seq.count(x) == n for x in seq), n)
```

Some quick tests:

```
tests = [
    [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5],
    [1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5],
    [1,2,2],
    [1,1,2],
    [1,2,3],
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, "-", has_one_value_repeated_n_times(test, 2))
```

Giving us:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] - True
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] - False
[1, 2, 2] - True
[1, 1, 2] - True
[1, 2, 3] - False
```

Comment: Still the same problem as with one other solution. The list `1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5` will return true in this case, no? That's not exactly two dupes. Even allowing for a list size of three, 1,1,1 will return true for your function despite it being wrong.

Comment: And downvote reversed though you should probably make it clear that this works only for the three-item list.

Comment: Added the even narrower solution.

Comment: **This is an O(N^2) algorithm.** Do not use this for large lists (e.g. 1000+ elements) or where performance is a factor.

Comment: @ninjagecko Indeed, given the OP is talking about length 3 lists and possibly longer, I presumed that performance would not be a huge issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
2 in collections.Counter(yourList).values()
```

Short and efficient.

If you mean "exactly" as in "among the multiplicities of elements, there is exactly one element with multiplicity 2", then you do:

```
Counter(Counter(yourList).values()).get(2)==1
```

Comment: `[1,2,2,3,3]` will return True, which doesn't fulfill the 'exactly' requirement

Comment: @mlauria: It does, unless you mean "exactly" as in "among the multiplicities of elements, there is exactly one element with multiplicity 2". In which case: `Counter(Counter(yourList).values()).get(2)==1`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but here's some pseudocode:

```
for i in 0 to length(list):
    j = indexOf(list, list[i], i + 1) > -1

    if j > -1 and indexOf(list, list[i], j + 1) == -1:
        // Found exactly two!
```

It should be efficient enough for your needs.

EDIT: Okay, I turned it into Python. Sorry if it's not good code.

```
def exactlyTwo(l):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l)):
        try:
            j = l.index(l[i], i + 1)

            try:
                l.index(l[i], j + 1)
            except ValueError:
                return True
        except ValueError:
            # Do nothing. Not sure how to do that in Python.
            0

    return False
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/0zzx030X)

Comment: `pass` is how you do that in Python, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this: `len(set(my_list)) == 2`

But then I see that in the case (3 items) where that works, we can do much better:
`> python -c 'from timeit import Timer; t1 = Timer("a[0] == a[1] != a[2] or a[0] == a[2] != a[1] or a[1] == a[2] != a[0]", setup="""a=["one","one","two"]"""); t2 = Timer("len(set(a)) == 2", setup="""a=["one","one","two"]"""); print t1.timeit(), t2.timeit()'`

`0.893960952759 2.28438997269`

Comment: This checks that the list only contains two distinct elements, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: The title of the question says two of three, and the question asks for the most efficient.
`> python -c 'from timeit import Timer; t1 = Timer("len(set(a)) == 2", setup="""a=["one","one","two"]"""); t2 = Timer("len(set(a)) == len(a) - 1", setup="""a=["one","one","two"]"""); print t1.timeit(), t2.timeit()'`
`2.32463097572 2.84631896019`

Comment: The full question states "However, if the list were larger, the task of writing out each possibility for a pair would become very difficult and time consuming." and makes no mention of lists with only three elements. Perhaps some clarification from the OP is required.

Comment: @Michael, as stated, the _title_ states "two of three" as does the example in the question. I see if "if the list were larger" bit as a secondary question.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you have (at least for lists of size three) - it's readable and fairly succinct and you should really only worry about performance *if* it becomes a problem.

The chances of a solution like set conversion being much faster than three conditionals is unlikely though not impossible.

I'd prefer a slightly different form to reduce "indentation hell" :-)

```
if list[0] == list[1] and list[1] != list[2]:
    return True

if list[1] == list[2] and list[2] != list[0]:
    return True

if list[0] == list[2] and list[2] != list[1]:
    return True

return False
```

Or, if you prefer to see as much code at once on your screen/printout:

```
if list[0] == list[1] and list[1] != list[2]: return True
if list[1] == list[2] and list[2] != list[0]: return True
if list[0] == list[2] and list[2] != list[1]: return True
return False
```

For larger arrays, you can turn it into a set and, if the length of the set is one less than the length of the array, there was exactly one duplicate:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> len(a) == len (set(a)) + 1
True
```

Comment: There's also the concern of dealing with larger lists.

Comment: @MichaelMior, I've added to the end for larger lists but the question title explicitly stated two of three. The body asked for a solution where the list is larger which is why I added the set variant.

Comment: @paxdiablo this latter solution is incomplete as it's assuming there is not any other items having same values.

Comment: @okm, not sure I understand. Since the set removes dupes, the _only_ situation in which the length of the set is one less than the length of the array is when every element in the array is unique except for one, which has exactly two entries. Any other case will involve a length difference of something other than 1. For example, `1,2,2,2,3` will result in a difference of 2, `1,2,3` gives a difference of 0, `1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4` gives a difference of 6 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If only one/none of the elements are repeated, and you can represent the elements as positive integers (say by mapping "one" to 1 using a dict)

Then the following solution would work

```
def find_repeated_element(l):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x^y, l + list(set(l)))

l = [1,1,2]
>>> find_repeated_element(l)
1
l = [1,2,3]
>>> find_repeated_element(l)
0
l = [1,1,1]
>>> find_repeated_element(l)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we need to do pairwise comparisons, how about using `itertools.product` to create a sequence of all of the pair comparisons?

```
from itertools import product

tests = """\
AAB
ABC
ABB
ABA
AAA""".splitlines()

def has_exactly_one_doubled_element(t):
    return sum(map(lambda a:a[0]==a[1], product(t,t))) == 5

for t in tests:
    print t, has_exactly_one_doubled_element(t)
```

prints:

```
AAB True
ABC False
ABB True
ABA True
AAA False
```

So then, how did I come up with the magic number of 5? The pairs returned by product are each element paired with an element from a second copy of the list.  If all 3 are different, then they will each compare as equal to themselves but none others, so the total will be 3.  If 2 are the same, then in addition to the 3 matches, the two duplicates will compare equal to each other once in each direction, so add 2 to 3 to get 5.  If all 3 are the same, then each element will match with every other element, for 3*3 or 9 matches.

Here is a general solution for a list of any length, to see if there is exactly one duplicated value (also uses `operator.__eq__` and `itertools.starmap` to avoid passing a lambda to `map`):

```
from operator import __eq__ as EQ
from itertools import product, starmap

def has_exactly_one_doubled_element(t):
    return sum(starmap(EQ, product(t,t))) == len(t)+2

args = ["ABCD"]*4
tests = map(''.join, product(*args))
for t in tests:
    print t, has_exactly_one_doubled_element(t)
```

Prints:

```
AAAA False
AAAB False
AAAC False
AAAD False
AABA False
AABB False
AABC True
AABD True
AACA False
AACB True
AACC False
AACD True
AADA False
AADB True
AADC True
AADD False
ABAA False
ABAB False
ABAC True
ABAD True
ABBA False
ABBB False
ABBC True
ABBD True
ABCA True
ABCB True
ABCC True
ABCD False
ABDA True
ABDB True
ABDC False
ABDD True
ACAA False
ACAB True
ACAC False
ACAD True
ACBA True
ACBB True
ACBC True
ACBD False
ACCA False
ACCB True
ACCC False
ACCD True
ACDA True
ACDB False
ACDC True
ACDD True
ADAA False
ADAB True
ADAC True
ADAD False
ADBA True
ADBB True
ADBC False
ADBD True
ADCA True
ADCB False
ADCC True
ADCD True
ADDA False
ADDB True
ADDC True
ADDD False
BAAA False
BAAB False
BAAC True
BAAD True
BABA False
BABB False
BABC True
BABD True
BACA True
BACB True
BACC True
BACD False
BADA True
BADB True
BADC False
BADD True
BBAA False
BBAB False
BBAC True
BBAD True
BBBA False
BBBB False
BBBC False
BBBD False
BBCA True
BBCB False
BBCC False
BBCD True
BBDA True
BBDB False
BBDC True
BBDD False
BCAA True
BCAB True
BCAC True
BCAD False
BCBA True
BCBB False
BCBC False
BCBD True
BCCA True
BCCB False
BCCC False
BCCD True
BCDA False
BCDB True
BCDC True
BCDD True
BDAA True
BDAB True
BDAC False
BDAD True
BDBA True
BDBB False
BDBC True
BDBD False
BDCA False
BDCB True
BDCC True
BDCD True
BDDA True
BDDB False
BDDC True
BDDD False
CAAA False
CAAB True
CAAC False
CAAD True
CABA True
CABB True
CABC True
CABD False
CACA False
CACB True
CACC False
CACD True
CADA True
CADB False
CADC True
CADD True
CBAA True
CBAB True
CBAC True
CBAD False
CBBA True
CBBB False
CBBC False
CBBD True
CBCA True
CBCB False
CBCC False
CBCD True
CBDA False
CBDB True
CBDC True
CBDD True
CCAA False
CCAB True
CCAC False
CCAD True
CCBA True
CCBB False
CCBC False
CCBD True
CCCA False
CCCB False
CCCC False
CCCD False
CCDA True
CCDB True
CCDC False
CCDD False
CDAA True
CDAB False
CDAC True
CDAD True
CDBA False
CDBB True
CDBC True
CDBD True
CDCA True
CDCB True
CDCC False
CDCD False
CDDA True
CDDB True
CDDC False
CDDD False
DAAA False
DAAB True
DAAC True
DAAD False
DABA True
DABB True
DABC False
DABD True
DACA True
DACB False
DACC True
DACD True
DADA False
DADB True
DADC True
DADD False
DBAA True
DBAB True
DBAC False
DBAD True
DBBA True
DBBB False
DBBC True
DBBD False
DBCA False
DBCB True
DBCC True
DBCD True
DBDA True
DBDB False
DBDC True
DBDD False
DCAA True
DCAB False
DCAC True
DCAD True
DCBA False
DCBB True
DCBC True
DCBD True
DCCA True
DCCB True
DCCC False
DCCD False
DCDA True
DCDB True
DCDC False
DCDD False
DDAA False
DDAB True
DDAC True
DDAD False
DDBA True
DDBB False
DDBC True
DDBD False
DDCA True
DDCB True
DDCC False
DDCD False
DDDA False
DDDB False
DDDC False
DDDD False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def exactlyTwo(elements):
    return sum(elements.count(i)-1 for i in elements) == 2
```

works for unhashable elements, and where 'exactly two elements' means triplets and two doubles should return False

Answer (score -1):

```
def checkk(lis):
  sett=set(lis)
  for ele in sett:
     if lis.count(ele)==2:
       return 'yes'
  else:
     return 'no'


x=list(["one", "one", "two"])
y=list(["one", "two", "three"])
z=list(["one", "one", "one"])
w=list(["one", "two", "two"])
print(checkk(x))
print(checkk(y))
print(checkk(z))
print(checkk(w))
```

**output:**

```
yes
no
no
yes
```

Comment: And for one/two/two, what does this do (once you fix the indentation of course)?

Comment: @paxdiablo indentation is perfect(for-else loop). code is running fine and i added one/two/two to the solution, it returns 'yes'.

Comment: `for-else` - well, bugger me, I never knew such a beast even existed. +1 for educating me. One question, why would you just not return `no` no matter what (ie, ditch the `else` line)?

Comment: The question asked about exactly two elements, how would your code work for [1,1,2,2] ?

Comment: @Akavall, the question _title_ specified two from three. There's an extra question in the body about how to handle larger lists but I still consider an answer on the _primary_ question to be useful. That's my thoughts on the matter though, as my wife would say (often and without much encouragement), I've been wrong before :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo well the trick is, in for-else loop the else part runs only when the for loop completes successfully(without any break or return)

Answer (score -2):

You could try

```
list(["one", "one", "two"]).count("one") == 2
```